# htaccess redirect regex for subfolder and files, not parent

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I have a regular expression set up now:

```
^/technology/(.*)$
```

It works great for all the subfolders and files. The problem is that I don't want it to redirect when it's only the technology folder, though.

```
/technology/ FALSE
/technology/something/ TRUE
/technology/something/else/ TRUE
```

Sorry - I'm a regex newb!

Answer (score 3):

try this regexp:

```
^/technology/(.+)$
```

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to give you a +!  That was it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

May be `/technology/(\w.+?)` will work like in php?